# Function for coordinate of user Location on swift

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates

I've implemented the code for the determine the position of user location.
Is there a function that return me the coordinate?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: There are many functions of locationManager and MapView. My question is there is a function of CoreLocation.... sorry for my bad Ebglish

Comment: Resolved -_-.
Excuse for my question...i'm a douch****!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this source:
http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/

For details on location, refer to Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Comment: Because i revolved equally your respond